# AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights - replace string function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How do I use AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights' **replace** function?

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) do not give working examples.

Given logs which contain paths such as `/api/lumberjack/123/axe/456/fashion`

I am trying:

```
fields message
| parse message "path=* " as path
| fields replace(path, /[0123456789]+/, 'ID') as uniqpath
| stats count(*) by uniqpath
```

I expect results like:

```
uniqpath | count
/api/lumberjack/ID/axe/ID/fashion | 12
/api/lumberjack/ID/beardedness | 44
```

But instead it complains "Invalid arguments, received: (path) but expected: (str: string,searchValue: string,replaceValue: string)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `replace` function accepts fields as input for the first argument.

What is not supported is the second argument. You are passing a regex which is not recognized as a string.

I have not found a way to convert the regex to string. But at least you can pass the fieldname `path` for the first param. I have tested it changing the regex for a normal string.

Query:

```
fields @message
| parse @message "path=*" as path
| fields replace(path, 'lumberjack', 'ID') as uniqpath
| stats count(*) by uniqpath
```

Results:

[image: Query results]

Comment: ah! I was using `replace` function with the `filter` command instead of `fields` command. Thank you so much! I was about to go mad and AWS Cloudwatch Query help documentation is not detailed enough

Answer (score 4):

You can't replace by regex in one step, which would be ideal. Instead, you must tease out a possible id, coalesce to give it a default value, then replace that explicit value with a placeholder. This will allow you to get endpoint counts regardless of specific record ids.

This simple version works for endpoints that have AT MOST one id:

```
filter path like /\/api\/v/
| parse path /(?<@id1>\/[0-9]+)(\/|$)/
| fields coalesce(@id1, "") as id1
| fields replace(path, id1, "/{id}") as unique_path
| stats count(*) as requests by unique_path
| sort requests desc
| display unique_path, requests
```

If your record ids are more complex, you can update the regex accordingly. I had to do this because some of our app's endpoints accept ids as hex strings, ie "0x04f5".

This next version will work for up to 2 ids. For more, you can see how to repeat the given pattern, but I didn't find a shortcut for n-count ids in a URL path.

```
filter path like /\/api\/v/
| parse path /(?<@id1>\/[0-9]+)(\/|$)/
| fields coalesce(@id1, "") as id1
| fields replace(path, id1, "/{id}") as unique_path1
| parse unique_path1 /(?<@id2>\/[0-9]+)(\/|$)/
| fields coalesce(@id2, "") as id2
| fields replace(unique_path1, id2, "/{id2}") as unique_path
| stats count(*) as requests by unique_path
| sort requests desc
| display unique_path, requests
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. The `replace` function expects an input of type string for the first argument. You provided a fieldname `path` which is not acceptable.

**EDIT:** To my surprise, the `replace` function accepts path as the first argument, which is not mentioned in the doc. See Omar's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but I've once made something similar to that so yours should be something like the following:

```
fields @message
| parse @message "path=* " as path
| parse path /(?<@endpt>(\/[0123456789]+\/?))/
| fields replace(path, coalesce(@endpt, ''), '/{id}/') as uniqpath
| stats count(*) by uniqpath
```

Comment: i had better luck with the coalesce on the outside of the replace: | fields coalesce(replace(path, pathid, '{id}'), path) as resourcePath